# Reuse a block of code in several places in jinja2

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have this html snippet which needs to be used in lots of places in the jinja2 templates:

```
<div class="usedalot">{{  somevalue }}</div>
```

for example, in template1.html, template2.html. template3.html, this code is repeated several places

```
<!-- template1.html, template2.html. template3.html -->
<div class="usedalot">{{  somevalue }}</div>
......
<div class="usedalot">{{  somevalue }}</div>
....
<div class="usedalot">{{  somevalue }}</div>
......
```

Instead of copying and pasting, is there someway to use this code snippet as a block? The jinja2 template inheritance (with blocks) do not seem to solve this problem.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a [macro](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#macros).

Macros are placed in separate files (e.g., `macros.html`).

```
{% macro usedalot(somevalue) %}
    <div class="usedalot">{{ somevalue }}</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

You can then import your macros in other templates

```
{% from 'macros.html' import usedalot %}
```

and then use them whenever needed

```
{{ usedalot(1) }}
```

This will output

```
<div class="usedalot">1</div>
```

Comment: that's so incredibly ugly though. I mean it looks ok if your argument is `1`. What if your argument is a BIG piece of HTML?

Comment: Why are you defining HTML inside a string literal in a template? That sounds like a code smell.

Comment: no. I am telling, I don't want to do exactly that. The question is:  how can I do it? see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113110/jinja2-templating-with-components-blocks-templates

Answer (score 21):

As of Jinja 2.8, you can also now use block assignments to map a block (still can only be defined once) to a variable that can be used multiple times in the document.

Documentation is at: [Block assignments](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/latest/templates/#block-assignments)

I just used the feature to drop my HTML page title block into both the title element as well as the meta property for Facebook's opengraph:title attribute.

```
{% set title_s %}{% block title %}MY DEFAULT TITLE{% endblock %}{% endset %}
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ title_s }}" />
<title>{{ title_s }}</title>
...
</head>
```

This seems to me to be a much more clean solution than defining a macro.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works great here in 2019 with Flask :)

Comment: This is a good solution.  I don't believe the {% block title %} {% endblock %} is needed with block assignments

Comment: This is just using a variable in multiple places. I think James was after a reusable/parameterisable code block. Sth. like you can call like a function with variables.

Comment: exactly what I needed - simple and allows variables parametrization. I had to use a block inside it though to make it work, exactly like described.

Answer (score 0):

[Jinja's documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#child-template) today states:

> If you want to print a block multiple times, you can, however, use the special self variable and call the block with that name:
>
> ```
> <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
> <h1>{{ self.title() }}</h1>
> {% block body %}{% endblock %}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`include` is what I was looking for.

Example from [docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#include):

```
{% include 'header.html' %}
Body goes here.
{% include 'footer.html' %}
```