# jinja2 insert pure html code

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a common header that I want to show up on multiple pages. So I want to use jinja2 to inject the code snippet. The snippet is basically `<div> ....</div>`. So to insert it I have been trying to use `{{header }}` or `{{ header | escape}}` or `{{ header | safe }}`. None of these have worked. Does anyone know how to insert **raw** html code into an html template using jinja2?

Comment: I found the easiest way to be using macros as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21275796/2223706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to redesign your templates to use [Template Inheritance](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#template-inheritance). This feature designed for such tasks: put everything common for all pages to a master template, then use `{% extends master.html %}` in a particular page template.