# Jinja2 templating with components? blocks? templates?

Tags: django, jinja2

A little question to **jinja2** templating:
I want to create a reusable template to include and then overwrite blocks. Macros do not let me write junks of HTML easily as parameters do they? Say I want to reuse an include several times and am using BIG junks of HTML in blocks that I want to dynamically assign
how would I do it?

certainly not with macros I guess, or am I wrong?

`{% render_foo('bar',2) %}` is fine

`{% render_foo('<table><tr><th>something</th><th>somethingelse</th></tr><tbody><tr>....etc') %}` is not fine any more is it

"what do you really want to do?"

yes, what I told you, I have a way I create containers for my data. The container is ALWAYS the same. The content is *completely* different on each usage. Once a table. Once a bootstrap component. Once a form.

The surrounding elements are always the same

to reproduce the simple error this is what I did:

```
 {% include 'full_section.html' %}
  {% block fullsection %} <table><tr><th>something</th><th>somethingelse</th></tr><tbody><tr>....etc{% endblock %}

  {% include 'full_section.html' %}
  {% block fullsection %} <form>//some cool LONG big form </form>{% endblock %}
```

`full_section.html` contents just for completeness, it is a lot more complex in reality

```
<div class="my_cool_full_section">
{% block full_section %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

> TemplateAssertionError: block 'fullsection' defined twice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer *well hidden* in the jinja2 docs

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#block-assignments

so you use a macro and a block assignment e.g. like this:

```
{% set section_content %}
<table><tr><td>etc</td> <td>etc</td> <td>etc</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>etc</td> <td>etc</td> <td>etc</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>etc</td> <td>etc</td> <td>etc</td></tr></table>
  {% endset %}
  {{  render_full_size_section(section_content)  }}


  {% set section_content %}
  aaaaaaaaaaa
    {% endset %}
    {{  render_full_size_section(section_content)  }}
```

wonder what they were doing pre 2.8... dark dark middle age

then in the macro:

```
{% macro render_full_size_section(content) %}
<div class="mycoolsection">
  {{ content | safe }}
</div>
{% endmacro %}
```