# How can I repeat a nunjucks block in the same file?

Tags: nunjucks

I'm working on a static site that is using gulp and nunjucks.

For example, say I have a block for an article's title that I want to display in two places on the same page. How would I implement that?

I saw in jinja that you could do something like `{% set title_s %}{% block title %}MY DEFAULT TITLE{% endblock %}{% endset %}` in [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275375/reuse-a-block-of-code-in-several-places-in-jinja2), but that doesn't seem to work in nunjucks. I just get the text "undefined" when I use `{{title_s}}`.

Edit: I ended up just using `{% set title %}PAGE TITLE{% endset %}` in the child template. This means I can use that value inside the parent template. I'm not sure now which way is proper.

Answer (score 1):

One way to use a block more than once is to set it as a variable in your template on the first use, then use `{{ title }}` twice

```html
{% set title %}{% block title %}{% endblock %}{% endset %}
<title>{{ title }}</title>
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understand your question clearly, but see this example if that what you are asking for

article.njk

```
{% macro articleMacro(title, headerOnly = false) %}
  <article>
    {% if headerOnly %}
      <header>{{title}}</header>
    {% else %}
      <header>{{title}}</header>
      <p>article body</p>
      <footer></footer>
    {% endif %}
  </article>
{% endmacro %}
```

page.njk

```
{% import "article.njk" as article %}

// this will render full article
{{ article('header one', false) }}

// this will render article header
{{ article('header one', true) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I want to be able to repeat blocks because blocks they can be used to override blocks in the parent template. For example it "makes sense" when the user can do `{% set title %}Foo Article{% endset %}` and the title will update in all places it is used in the rendered template (for example in the title and also in a request for comments). Then you have a `{% set article %}Lorem Ipsum{% article %}`. Right now you can't use the content of the block in multiple places, so I did a workaround by setting variables and doing if statements with default values--not ideal.